# How to get all the results where parent is an item from an array

Tags: php, arrays, drupal

I have an array that consists names of parents ,I want to get all the results where any of the name is a parent.Here is my code.I am not able to get the list of names where parent is equal to the names in district array.

Here is my complete code.

```
<?php
$functionname = 'core_course_get_categories';
$username = array('key' => 'name', 'value' => '2016');
$params = array('criteria' => array($username));
$server_url = 'localhost/moodle' . '/webservice/rest/server.php' . '?wstoken=' . '9cdaccf3a7ad2f0f94922ccfd02559f4' . '&wsfunction=' . $functionname;
$rest_format = 'json';
require_once('curl.inc');
$curl = new curl;
$rest_format = ($rest_format == 'json') ? '&moodlewsrestformat=' . $rest_format : '';

$resp = $curl->post($server_url . $rest_format, $params);
$res = json_decode($resp);
// drupal_set_message('<pre>'. dpm($res) .'</pre>');
$district = array();
$Ctsc = array();
$School = array();
$Grade = array();
$parent = array();

foreach ($res as $r) {
    $a = $r->parent;
    $c = $r->name;
    if ($a == 0) {
        $b = $r->id;
        var_export($b);
    }
}
foreach ($res as $r) {

    if ($r->parent == $b) {
        //$dist=$r->name;
        $district[] = $r->name;
    }
}    

$Ctsc[] = $r->description;
$School[] = $r->sortorder;
$Grade[] = $r->depth;
foreach ($res as $r) {        
    $q = $r->name;
    if (in_array($q['parent'], $district)) {
        $Ctsc[] = $q->name;
        dpm($Ctsc);
    }
    if ($Ctsc['parent'] == $district) {

        dpm($Ctsc);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usage of `in_array()` is wrong.

Instead of

```
if(in_array($q['parent'] == $district)){ ... }
```

use

```
if(in_array($q['parent'], $district)){ ... }
```

Comment: what should i echo to get the names @maxhb

Comment: Please provide output of `var_export($res);` and  `var_export($b);`, so we can see the actual data.

Comment: $res consists of all the results as                                                              id (Integer) 7
name (String, 10 characters ) Rawalpindi
idnumber (String, 1 characters ) 6
description (String, 0 characters )
descriptionformat (Integer) 1
parent (Integer) 2
sortorder (Integer) 130000
coursecount (Integer) 0
visible (Integer) 1
visibleold (Integer) 1
timemodified (Integer) 1458285536
depth (Integer) 2
path (String, 4 characters ) /2/7
theme (NULL)

Comment: whereas $b has 2 in it

Comment: So you store all names in `$district` where parent is 2. And then you are looking for the names of the results where the name is in `$district`? As far as I understand you already have that list in `$district`...

Comment: I only need the names where district names are parents or any one of the ditrict name is a parent